# NiftyNet 'evaluation' action output is incorrect

Tags: niftynet

I'm trying to use the new 'evaluation' action after inference to generate some metrics for my output. However, the .csv files just show scores of '0' for average_distance and '1' for Jaccard and Dice for each of my data volumes. I can't seem to find any documentation for the evaluation action, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also, the `--dataset_to_infer=Validation` option doesn't seem to work, both inference and evaluation are being applied to all data rather than just the validation set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the evaluation issue, we're working on the documentation. The `dataset_to_infer` option is only tested for the applications in `NiftyNet/niftynet/application`; applications from the model zoo are not upgraded to support it yet (please file an issue with more details https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/issues if you believe it's a bug).

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, pointing directly to the inference result in the config.ini worked for me.

e.g.
`[inferred]
csv_file = model_dir/save_seg_dir/inferred.csv`

I believe this file is not found currently and then evaluation defaults to comparing labels to labels. See the [issue](https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/issues/289) on GitHub.